# VB.Net not evaluating on lines of code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Recently I've been having a problem in a small VB.Net program I've put together.  The program is using `OleDb` to control an Excel spreadsheet that we use to track some weekly checks at work.  The `OleDb` section is working fine, but I added a couple `RegEx` statements to validate some input, and one of the statements isn't working.  The `RegEx` is defined as

```
Private ReadOnly rgxTM As New Regex("^[T][M][ ]\d{4}$")`
```

and is evaluated as

```
If Not rgxTM.IsMatch(tm) Then
    MessageBox.Show("The tape measure number you entered is invalid.", "Invalid Tape Measure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Tb.Text = ""
    Exit Sub
End If
```

`tm` is defined as `tm = newForm.tmTb.Text.ToUpper`

After the `RegEx` is compared, it has an `OleDb.OleDbCommand` that it updates the `CommandText` for, clears the `Parameters` and sets them for the new `CommandText`, opens the `OleDb.OleDbConnection`, executes the `UPDATE` statement, and closes the connection.  Everything here is working, and I can see the new values being entered into the Excel spreadsheet live.

At first I thought the statements were never being entered into, however seeing the data update in the spreadsheet proved that it is passing through this section of nesting.  I placed a `MessageBox.Show` and passed in the dialog of `rgxTM.IsMatch(tm)`, and that `MessageBox` never shows up.  Furthermore, if I set any breakpoints in this section of nesting, the breakpoints are never hit, even when I set them on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` that is clearly updating my spreadsheet.

I've checked my debug configuration (Debug, Any CPU), compile configuration (I've tried Debug and Release, each with Any CPU and x86 selected), checked and unchecked "Require source files to exactly match the original version", and to the best of my knowledge, I haven't changed anything major with the actual settings since first starting up VS 2017.

Code snippet

```
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions    

Private ReadOnly conStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
Private ReadOnly con As New OleDbConnection With {
        .ConnectionString = conStr
    }
Private ReadOnly rgxTM As New Regex("^[T][M][ ]\d{4}$")
Private response As String

Dim cmdStr As String = "SELECT name, [Tape Measure Number], [Date Calibrated], [New Tape Measure Number] FROM [TAPE MEASURE LIST$] WHERE [Employee Number] = @gage"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand With {
    .CommandText = cmdStr,
    .Connection = con
}

Dim newForm As New NewForm("Please scan your new tape measure.")
response = newForm.ShowDialog()
If response <> vbOK Then
    Tb.Text = ""
    Exit Sub
Else
    tm = newForm.tmTb.Text.ToUpper
    MessageBox.Show(rgxTM.IsMatch(tm))
    If Not rgxTM.IsMatch(tm) Then
        MessageBox.Show("The tape measure number you entered is invalid.", "Invalid Tape Measure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Tb.Text = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [TAPE MEASURE LIST$] SET [NEW TAPE MEASURE NUMBER] = @tm, [DATE OF CHANGE] = @date WHERE [EMPLOYEE NUMBER] = @empnum"
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tm", tm)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empnum", gage)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Tb.Text = ""
End If
```

Any breakpoint that is entered inside the `else` statement is ignored; any other breakpoints that I use are hit normally.  I know it's entering the `else` statement since the `UPDATE` is executed.

I'm running this on Windows 7 Professional 64, using Office 2010 and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: My first hint for you (was not reading the rest): please replace the AddWithValue... it is a bad method. Did you try to set a breakpoint at the very first command of your function? Maybe a step-by-step will show you, where a problem is.

Comment: If you can hit any other breakpoint normally, what happens if you break on the `If` statement and then step through?

Comment: There are also some additional strategies you could use: `Debug.Assert` to verify program state (note that the expression in the assert will not compile into a release program, so make sure it doesn't change program state!); at the extreme, there is a Windows API function `DebugBreak` that will result in a hard breakpoint in your code.

Comment: @muffi I'm open to hearing a better way to handle that, although I'm not as particular since I'm using `OleDb` instead of `SQL`.  I've set a breakpoint on every line, as well as breaking on the block this is inside and stepping through it, and stepping through seems to hit the lines, but they never evaluate.  Setting breakpoints lets me move line by line until I hit this code block.

Comment: @Craig I added `Debug.Assert(rgxTM.IsMatch(tm))` after `MessageBox.Show(rgxTM.IsMatch(tm))` and it did pop up a window, which if I understand correctly, is the desired behavior since the statement did evaluate to `False` using the string `5101`.  So, it seems that it is evaluating some lines in the code, but I'm still not clear why every line isn't being evaluated.

Comment: To clarify: you got the assertion you expected, which behavior that you expected did you *not* get?  Did it not show the message box even though it should have?  Did you not see expected effects from running the command?  If the latter, then I would take a close look at the command; when I have run into that kind of behavior in the past, I usually had done something wrong in the command itself.

Comment: @Craig To my understanding, when the Boolean in `Debug.Assert` evaluates to `False`, it sends a failure message with Abort/Retry/Ignore.  I passed in `rgxTM.IsMatch(tm)`, with `tm = "5101"` and `rgxTM ` as stated in the above code.  The `MessageBox` did not show.  The update statement in `cmd.CommandText` still did process, and I saw the change in the Excel spreadsheet.  I expected the `RegEx` expression to trigger the `If` check and `Show` a `MessageBox` stating that the tape measure was invalid, clear `Tb.Text`, and `Exit Sub`, which is directly before the `OleDbCommand` is processed.

Comment: Are you setting the dialog result?  All I see you do in the quoted code above is `Exit Sub`.  You need to set the result on the dialog in order for your check on the return from `ShowDialog` to work.  I don't recall, offhand, if setting the Default Button and Cancel Button attributes will make that happen automatically; I think not, I think that just gives you the automatic enter key / escape key handling.

Comment: @Craig Yes, the dialog from `ShowDialog` is set through `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton`, and the same form is used in another location (The overload is setting the text in a label on the form).  The `Exit Sub` I was referring to is in the `If` block from `If Not rgxTM.IsMatch(tm)`.  When using `Debug.Assert(rgxTM.IsMatch(tm))`, I got a failure message with Abort/Retry/Ignore, which I believe means that `rgxTM.IsMatch(tm)` evaluated `False`.  If it is `False`, then `If Not rgxTM.IsMatch(tm)` should be `True` and trigger the three lines enclosed there.

Comment: That would mean that `IsMatch` evaluated to `False`.  Are you saying, then, that the issue is just that the `MessageBox` doesn't show and `Tb.Text` is not set to an empty string?  What about the part where you talk about the `OleDbCommand`?  That's in your second snippet, controlled by the dialog result returned from `newForm`.  Note that this dialog result is *not* set automatically by the framework; you must explicitly set it to some value other than its default (which is `False` for WPF, not sure for WinForms).  What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: `Debug.Assert(rgxTM.IsMatch(tm))` is between `MessageBox.Show(rgxTM.isMatch(tm))` and `If Not rgxTM.IsMatch(tm)`.  `Debug.Assert(rgxTM.IsMatch(tm))` fires and gives me a failure dialog.  The `MessageBox` directly before it never shows, nor does the If statement after it which should bail out of the routine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150749/discussion-between-malil-and-craig).